# Get ng-table filters values in angularjs

Tags: ngtable

I want to access the **ng-table filter** values applied by the user.  I have to use these filter values in my angularjs file.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your latest code?

Comment: Do you solve ur problem? I have the save problem also. Do you mind share your code?